# p5.js and p5.sound.js does not work with different machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html5-audio, p5.js

i just made one front-end HTML project which take audio from user using `p5.js` and `p5.sound.js`. 
Everything working fine with my HTML code. but when i integrated that HTML code with my `DJANGO` back-end. it works fine with only same computer(`localhost:8000/`). But when i try to access and run django app from different machine(like `192.168.0.43:8000`) it raise 
following **error** in browser console.

`
[image]

`

> there are following code in **sketch.js**

```
let mic, fft, level1, state, soundFile, recorder;
let can1;
var timer = null;

/** first setup the microphone **/
function setup() {
    state = 0;
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    can1 = createCanvas(400, 400);
    can1.parent('canvas-area');
    noFill();
    mic = new p5.AudioIn();
    mic.start(); //start mic
    fft = new p5.FFT();
    fft.setInput(mic);
}

/** when mic on draw the circle on canvas **/
function draw() {
    background(245, 247, 250);
    let spectrum = fft.analyze();
    // strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(61, 191, 232);
    beginShape();
    if (state == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
            vertex(i, map(spectrum[i], 0, 255, height, 0));
        }
    } else if ($('#record').text() == 'Resume') {
        textSize(32);
        text("Resume Recordering", 40, 180)
    } else {
        textSize(32);
        text("Click To Start Meeting", 40, 180)
    }
    endShape();
}



/** run following code when documnet is ready **/
$(document).ready(function(){

    /** do get request for check server response **/
    CheckServerResponse();

    /**  Start Meeting button and Resume button **/
    $('#record').click(function(){

        if (state === 0 && mic.enabled){
            getAudioContext().resume()
            recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
            recorder.setInput(mic);
            soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
            recorder.record(soundFile);
            console.log("play")
            $(this).text('Pause')
            $('#stop').removeAttr('hidden');
            state=1;
            request_counter=0;
            response_counter=0;
            response_text=[];
            timer=setTimeout(sendajexrequest,60000)
        }else{
            /** Pause button send the data in server **/
            recorder.stop(); 
            AjaxRequest();
            state=0;
            console.log("pause")
            $(this).text('Resume');

            if(timer)
            {
              clearTimeout(timer); //cancel the previous timer.
              timer = null;
            }
        }
    });

    /** Stop button send the data in server **/
    $("#stop").click(function(){

      if(state==1 && $("#record").text()=='Pause'){
        recorder.stop(); 
        console.log("after Stop")
        AjaxRequest()
        $('#record').prop('disabled','false');
      }
      $(this).attr('hidden','true');
      $('#record').html('Start Meeting')
      state=0;
      if(timer)
      {
        clearTimeout(timer); //cancel the previous timer.
        timer = null;
      }
      $('#loader-audio').removeAttr('hidden');
      $('#canvas-area').hide();
      $('#record').prop('disabled','true');
    });

  });
```

> Following file imported in **index.html**

```
    <script src="{% static 'js/p5.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/p5.sound.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/sketch.js' %}"></script>
```

> Note: Please avoid (if you don't know this) **`{% static 'js*.js' %}`**. It's django jinja syntax code and it works fine.

Please help me to fix this issue.

thanks

Comment: Have you allowed microphone/camera access to the site? How to do that depends on the browser you're using.

Comment: yeah. actually that is not problem when i works fine with localhost(same )machine. but when other machine access it does not work with another machine's browser.

Comment: Well, are you sure that other machine's browser _does_ support `getUserMedia`, like the error message implies it doesn't?

Comment: yeah that reason i installed my django-app in both machine. and it work fine with both machine's localhost(same machine's browser). i did cross check with both machine. but that problem only occur when accessed from one machine to  another machine.
so it is confirmed my both machine support `getUserMedia`

Comment: That implies there's a problem with the browser "trusting" your site (when it's not localhost but just a "random" remote IP) enough to do `getUserMedia()`. (I bet things might be better with HTTPS.) Which browser, version and OS is this, anyway?

Comment: Umm.. Firefox version `73.0.1` and Chome Version `79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) ` and `Manjaro 18.1.5 plasma KDE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208688/discussion-between-devang-hingu-and-akx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that [p5.sound AudioIn](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.AudioIn) most likely requires a `localhost` or `https` connection (especially in Chrome and Firefox). You can solve this by running an http-proxy to forward an https address to your localhost server. Check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-expose) if you want it to be accessible remotely/online, or check out nodejs' [http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#using-https) if you want to run it offline within local network. Once your app is online, just be sure to host it on an https server. Most web-hosts let you activate free [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) certificates on your domain.